# As we call `#!/bin/perl` 'shebang', what we call `-*- perl -*-`?

Tags: vim, emacs, vi, terminology

The first line of a script may be in format of `#! interpreter`, so the shell will execute the script using the specific *interpreter*. This is so called `shebang` or `shbang`.

Similarly, there can be some special comment like

```
# -*- language -*-
```

or

```
# vim: tabstop=4 :
```

etc. Just like `shbang` is used to denote which interpreter to use, these comments are used to adjust the editor's behavior.

How to call these special comments? Maybe `shdash` or `shvim`? Are there some already defined slangs for these?

And is there wiki pages to show the list of `shxxx`, and those softwares follow such conventions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are called modelines, at least in vim. See `:help modeline` -- not exactly slang, but at least it's something to call them.

Comment: They're called modelines in emacs too. There's even an emacs module to let it parse vim modelines.

Comment: Yeah. I've also found that, `vi` by default doesn't enable modelines, while `vim` does.